# What's the difference between the Find Steed and Find Greater Steed spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, summoning, mount

What's the difference between the *find steed* and *find greater steed* spells?

I found the *find steed* and *find greater steed* spells while playing 5e. By the rules as written, they seem almost identical except for the spell level and what they have listed as an example for the creature summoned. Is that the only difference, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The summoned creatures have major differences, from dogs to griffons. Don't neglect that detail!

Comment: Related: [Can Find Steed be used to replicate the effects of Find Greater Steed?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113019/can-find-steed-be-used-to-replicate-the-effects-of-find-greater-steed)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## *Find Greater Steed* generally provides more powerful creatures

Below is a table showcasing the creatures that can be summoned by each spell.

| **Find Steed** |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Name** | **CR** | **HP** | **Speed** | **Attack(s)** | **Special** |
| **Warhorse** | 1/2 | 19 (11AC) | 60ft. | +6: 2d6+4 | Trampling Charge |
| **Pony** | 1/8 | 11 (10AC) | 40ft. | +4: 2d4+2 |  |
| **Camel** | 1/8 | 15 (9AC) | 50ft. | +5: 1d4 |  |
| **Elk** | 1/4 | 13 (10AC) | 50ft. | +5: 1d6+3 | Charge |
| **Mastiff** | 1/8 | 5 (12AC) | 40ft. | +3: 1d6+1 | Hearing |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **Find Greater Steed** |  |  |  |  |  |
| **Name** | **CR** | **HP** | **Speed** | **Attack(s)** | **Special** |
| **Griffon** | 2 | 59 (12AC) | 80ft.* | 2x(+6: 2d6+4) | Keen Sight |
| **Pegasus** | 2 | 59 (12AC) | 90ft.* | +6: 2d6+4 |  |
| **Peryton** | 2 | 33 (13AC) | 60ft.* | 2x(+5: 1d8+3) | Flyby; Dive Attack |
| **Dire Wolf** | 1 | 37 (14AC) | 50ft. | +5: 2d6+3 | Pack Tactics |
| **Rhinoceros** | 2 | 45 (11AC) | 40ft. | +7: 2d8+5 | Charge |
| **Saber-Toothed Tiger** | 2 | 52 (12AC) | 40ft. | +6: 2d6+5 | Pounce |

<sup>*Flying Speed</sup>
<sup>†Full name: *Keen Hearing and Smell*</sup>

Although these stats don't tell the full story, it's pretty clear that the *Find Greater Steed* creatures are not just more powerful, but *substantially* more powerful. Their stats are a lot better, their features are a lot better, their movement speeds are higher, and many of them can fly, providing powerful mobility advantages.

So the difference between the spells isn't incidental: the *Find Greater Steed* creatures are simply stronger in nearly every way, hence the increased Spell Level.

Comment: Is there a list somewhere of ALL the creatures that can be summoned by both spells or is that up to the GM's discretion?

Comment: @Thatguy This is that list. *Find Steed* has the stipulation that the DM can permit additional creature types, but only at their discretion, so there's no list that could encompass all those additional potential creature types.

Comment: Rather than adding my own addendum answer, I'd recommend you also add that only *find greater steed* has the text qualifier of "You control the mount in combat." That mileage may vary based on how tables treat mounted combat with intelligent mounts, but that's a big RAW difference.

Comment: @NautArch: I disagree that that's really a meaningful distinction. See also: [How does a mount from Find Steed act when unmounted?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/99903/33569), [Do steeds summoned with Find Greater Steed have other options than the usual control rules during mounted combat?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/137336/33569), [Is a pegasus summoned by Find Greater Steed controlled or independent when mounted?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/116649/33569)

Answer (score 3):

You may have read an earlier version of the spell's text. [In August 2017, the errata document for the Player's Handbook included a change to the *find steed* spell.](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/sage-advice/rules-references-august-2017)

Originally its wording sounded more open ended:

> Appearing in an unoccupied space within range, the steed takes on a form that you choose, such as a warhorse, a pony, a camel, an elk, or a mastiff.

[Post-errata,](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-steed) the phrase 'such as' was removed, making those five creatures the only possible choices. (Barring DM permission, as the spell mentions.)

> Appearing in an unoccupied space within range, the steed takes on a form that you choose: a warhorse, a pony, a camel, an elk, or a mastiff.

That errata came out just 3 months before the *find greater steed* spell was published in Xanathar's Guide to Everything, which had the same strict phrasing as the post-errata version of *find steed*.

> Appearing in an unoccupied space within range, the spirit takes on a form you choose: a griffon, a pegasus, a peryton, a dire wolf, a rhinoceros, or a saber-toothed tiger.

Comment: Are you answering the original question or providing commentary to Xirema's answer?